# Parsing JSON to Java object 4

Tags: json

How to parse nested JSON to Java

```
{       
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": [{
                "value": "New",
                "onclick": "CreateNewDoc"
            }, {
                "value": "Open",
                "onclick": "OpenDoc"
            }, {
                "value": "Close",
            "onclick": "CloseDoc"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other modifiers, not only public

```
public class MainMenu {

    public Menu menu;

    public class Menu {

        public String id;
        public String value;
        public Popup popup;

        public class Popup {

            public List<Item> menuitem;

            public class Item {
                public String value;
                public String onclick;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Example

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json =     "{" +
                            "'menu': "+
                                "{" +
                                    "'id': 'file'," +
                                    "'value': 'File'," +
                                    "'popup': " +
                                        "{" +
                                            "'menuitem': " +
                                                "[{" +
                                                    "'value': 'New'," +
                                                    "'onclick': 'CreateNewDoc'" +
                                                   "}, {" +
                                                    "'value': 'Open'," +
                                                    "'onclick': 'OpenDoc'" +
                                                    "}, {" +
                                                    "'value': 'Close'," +
                                                    "'onclick': 'CloseDoc'" +
                                                "}]" +
                                        "}" +
                                "}" +
                            "}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        MainMenu mainMenu = gson.fromJson(json, MainMenu.class);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(mainMenu));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "value": "New",
          "onclick": "CreateNewDoc"
        },
        {
          "value": "Open",
          "onclick": "OpenDoc"
        },
        {
          "value": "Close",
          "onclick": "CloseDoc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "items": {
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters": {
          "batter": [
            {
              "id": "1001",
              "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
              "id": "1002",
              "type": "Chocolate"
            },
            {
              "id": "1003",
              "type": "Blueberry"
            },
            {
              "id": "1004",
              "type": "Devil's Food"
            }
          ]
        }
        "topping": [
          {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "None"
          },
          {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "Glazed"
          },
          {
            "id": "5005",
            "type": "Sugar"
          },
          {
            "id": "5007",
            "type": "Powdered Sugar"
          },
          {
            "id": "5006",
            "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
          },
          {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "Chocolate"
          },
          {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "Maple"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: we  want this json program in java